# How to styles labels only within fieldsets using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have tried all the possible ways mentioned on [CSS Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/), but I have not managed to change the style of the labels that are only inside `fieldset` element. Could you please inform me what I did wrong?

**View:**

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">                
            <div class="col-md-8 portfolio-item">

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Details</legend>

                    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item" >                            
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID):
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)
                        <br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name):
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
                        <br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname):
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Surname)
                        <br />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 portfolio-item" >
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department):
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Department)
                        <br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address):
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address)
                        <br />

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City):
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.City)
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried lots of different combinations of CSS Selectors in order to apply the styles only the labels inside `fieldset` elements as below:

**Css:**

```
fieldset > label {
        text-align: left !important;
        }

fieldset + label {
        text-align: left !important;
        }

div.row fieldset > label {
        text-align: left !important;
        }
```

Update : Here is rendered Html code

```
<div class="container">   
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 portfolio-item">

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Details</legend>

                    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">                            
                        <label for="ID">ID</label>:
                        200
                        <br>

                        <label for="Name">Name</label>:
                        Smith
                        <br>

                        <label for="Surname">Surname</label>:
                        Boyton
                        <br>
                    </div>

                    <!-- removed for brevity -->

                </fieldset>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this problem has anything to do with [tag:less]. Does the problem persist even with decompiled CSS? If so, you should post the pure HTML/CSS here and remove the unrelated tags.

Comment: I don't see label elements in the HTML, but for a structure like this:

Comment: i cant see any direct label in your code.

Comment: What is the DOM that is being generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
fieldset label {
  text-align: left;
}
```

The reason why your css wasn't working is because you were targetting the wrong elements. What you want is a *general descendant* for the fieldset. So any level of children will be affected.

You simplified HTML is:

```
<fieldset>
 <legend />
 <div>
   <label/>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

`fieldset > label` is finding a label that is the *direct child* of the fieldset. But since you have wrapped it in a div, this is not true.

`fieldset + label` is looking for a label that is a *sibling* of the fieldset (on the same level). The label is a child of the fieldset so this rule doesn't target what you want.

For more info on selectors in CSS take a quick read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors.

Small tip: in general you want to avoid using the `!important` declaration as it could override any changes you want to make in the future.

Comment: Many thanks. I also tried this way but it did not worked for the first time (maybe I use `legend` instead of `fieldset`). but now it works :)

Answer (score 4):

It should be just:

```
    fieldset label {
        text-align: left;
    }
```

The '>' symbol is the direct child selector i.e. theres a DIV between your fieldset and label which would be the direct child of fieldset

Also the '+' symbol is the next sibling selector which is why that won't work